# Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported in WCF RIA Services

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, wcf-ria-services

I've been following the walkthrough for creating your first WCF RIA Services Application from Microsoft and have encountered a problem when trying to edit and update data using the SubmitChanges() method of the Data Context.

The table being updated has an Identity Specification set in SQL Server 2008 on the 'CourseID' column. However the PRIMARY key is a composite of two other fields.

When using SubmitChanges() the application locks up in the browser an presents an unhandled exception. By handling this exception I managed to get the message: Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. This is referring to the 'CourseID' column.

Turning identity specification off solves the problem, but I need the auto-incrementing ID. In what way isn't this supported. Or where am I going wrong?

Comment: This should work (though I've only done it in EF, not RIA Services), but make sure the `StoreGeneratedPattern` is set correctly for CourseID in EDMX.

Comment: I'm trying to think why on earth you would have a structure like that. If you have  a surrogate key that should be your PK, the other two should have a unique index yes, but composite keys are a very poor choice for a PK for performance reasons and for the difficulty of updating information when it changes.

Comment: @HLGEM I came to this conclusion shortly after leaving work yesterday. The database structure is the problem here. Thanks for reinforcing that thought. I will close the question off.

Comment: We are running into this issue also. I see no reason why EF shouldn't support this. We have the Identity field to have a clustered index on to reduce/prevent table/index fragments. EF should certainly support an identity field that isn't the PK.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The database structure is at fault here.

Comment: Can you explain why the database structure was wrong? I'm running into the same issue but I'm using automatically generated fields by Azure Mobile Services.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment above specifies you need to set the StoreGeneraratedPattern to "Computed".

While you can change this on the Model Designer which changes the value in the CSDL. However for it to work the value also has to be changed in the SSDL. The only way to change this is to modify the XML by hand.

Keep in mind various things like "Update model from database" will regenerate the SSDL... so you have to reapply you changes.

Comment: this change by hand ignore the property in create and edit, if this property have the value "default value" if in edit you want change the value this property is ignored and still the value "default value" after edit

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this issue: add the [RoundtripOriginal] attribute to the corresponding property in your entity's metadata class.

See Jeff Handley's response in this Silverlight Forums discussion:

[WCF RIA Bug: Changes include "Identity" column DomainDataSource( "Indentity" column no modify), WCF RIA does not support](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/208377/490667.aspx)